# HP PC screen goes black after unplugging power cord

Tags: laptop

For the past few days, I've been having trouble with my HP laptop's screen. Whenever I unplug the power cord from the PC, my screen goes almost black. You can only see the screen a little bit if you hold a flashlight to it. When I re-plug the power cord, the PC screen is still dark. The screen would go back to normal if I close it and log in again. Even with the PC being plugged in to the power cord, the screen still goes black after a few hours. I've tried going to the control panel and adjusting my battery settings, but that didn't help. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: How old is the battery? Sounds like time for a new one.

Comment: I think it's about 4 years old.

Answer (score 0):

As LCD's dont produce light by themselves, they need illumination to produce a visible image. A backlight illuminates the screen from the side or back of the panel.

If your screen goes so black that you need an external light source to still see something, it would seem to me your LCD backlight stopped working.

Since it can be reset, it would seem there's some kind of short circuit or overheating problem. Not the backlight itself doesnt give off much heat, it's probably in some circuitry that drives it.